# swift 4 multiple picker view not working. I have three arrays ,but only "strBlood" is showing

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

**swift 4 multiple picker view not working. I have three arrays ,but only "strBlood" is showing the accurate array , other strcountry and strgender are not showing in the picker view and when I click on to the third label code crashes giving me the error of signal sigbart**

multiple picker views are not showing the data in the picker view in swift 4, I already read many tutorials but no one solve my problem please check and answer me.
when I implemented 3 picker views the data is showing only of the first picker view i.e , (strblood) but not the other arrays

the code below is working properly but there is one error regarding showing the array in the picker view when clciked on the other labels ("lblblood"."lblcountry")

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController  {

    var strBlood = ["O+","O-","O","A","B+"]
    var  strcountry = ["India","Canada","USA"]
    var strgender = ["Male","Female"]

    var selectedBlood: String?
    var selectedCountry: String?
    var selectedGender: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var txtGender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtCountry: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblBloodGroup: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             self.chooseCountry()
             self.chooseBlood()
             self.choosGender()
    }

    func chooseBlood(){
        let bloodPicker = UIPickerView()
        bloodPicker.delegate = self
        self.lblBloodGroup.inputView = bloodPicker
    }

    func chooseCountry(){

        let countryname = UIPickerView()
        countryname.delegate = self
        self.txtCountry.inputView = countryname
    }
    func choosGender() {

    let gender1 = UIPickerView()
    gender1.delegate = self
    self.txtGender.inputView = gender1
    }

}
extension RegisterViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if lblBloodGroup.isEnabled {
            print("BLOOD SELECTED")
           return strBlood.count

        }
        else if txtCountry.isEnabled{
            print("COUNTRY SELECTED")

            return strcountry.count
        }else {
             print("GENDER SELECTED")
            return strgender.count
        }

        }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if lblBloodGroup.isEnabled{
            print("BLOOD SELECTED1")
            return strBlood[row]


        }else if txtCountry.isEnabled{

            return strcountry[row]
        }else {
            return strgender[row]
        }

       }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
        if lblBloodGroup.isEnabled{
            selectedBlood = strBlood[row]
            lblBloodGroup.text = selectedBlood

        }else if txtCountry.isEnabled{
            selectedCountry = strcountry[row]
            txtCountry.text = selectedCountry
        }else {
            selectedGender = strgender[row]
            txtGender.text = selectedGender
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting your view controller as the delegate to three separate picker views. That means that all three picker views will display the data you provide them in the `titleForRow` function.

Inside that function, you check whether `lblBloodGroup.isEnabled`. This will always be `true` or `false` for all pickers that try to get their data from the delegate, no matter which one. `lblBloodGroup.isEnabled` does **NOT** check the current picker you're getting data for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this `isEnabled` will not help. you need to use `isEditing` and it will be true if user click on any `UITextField` and your code will be:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

    var strBlood = ["O+","O-","O","A","B+"]
    var strcountry = ["India","Canada","USA"]
    var strgender = ["Male","Female"]

    var selectedBlood: String?
    var selectedCountry: String?
    var selectedGender: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var txtGender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtCountry: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblBloodGroup: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.chooseCountry()
        self.chooseBlood()
        self.choosGender()
    }

    func chooseBlood(){
        let bloodPicker = UIPickerView()
        bloodPicker.delegate = self
        self.lblBloodGroup.inputView = bloodPicker
    }

    func chooseCountry(){

        let countryname = UIPickerView()
        countryname.delegate = self
        self.txtCountry.inputView = countryname
    }
    func choosGender() {

        let gender1 = UIPickerView()
        gender1.delegate = self
        self.txtGender.inputView = gender1
    }
}
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if lblBloodGroup.isEditing {
            print("BLOOD SELECTED")
            return strBlood.count

        }
        else if txtCountry.isEditing{
            print("COUNTRY SELECTED")

            return strcountry.count
        }else {
            print("GENDER SELECTED")
            return strgender.count
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if lblBloodGroup.isEditing{
            print("BLOOD SELECTED1")
            return strBlood[row]


        }else if txtCountry.isEditing{

            return strcountry[row]
        }else {
            return strgender[row]
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
        if lblBloodGroup.isEditing{
            selectedBlood = strBlood[row]
            lblBloodGroup.text = selectedBlood

        }else if txtCountry.isEditing{
            selectedCountry = strcountry[row]
            txtCountry.text = selectedCountry
        }else {
            selectedGender = strgender[row]
            txtGender.text = selectedGender
        }
    }
}
```

And result will be:

[image]